# How to give a default value to a List in Scala?

Tags: java, list, scala

I have the following part of code which gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException`, I found the source and I know that I declared a variable but set it initially null and later in the program initialized it but I don't know how to give a default value without getting error! The List accepts two different types, `Float` and `RDD`.
Here is the part of the code that has problem in it:

```
case class RPN (sc:SparkContext, vp: VolumeProperty, var stack:List[Either[RDD[(Int, Array[Float])],Float]]) {

def this(s:SparkContext,v:VolumeProperty) = this(s,v,null); //Think here is the problem

def operand(x: Either[RDD[(Int, Array[Float])],Float]) = new RPN(sc,vp,stack = x :: stack) //gives error on this line
```

and I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I solve it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Nil` instead of `null`. `Nil` is an empty list.